# How can I fix "possible lossy conversion from double to int"?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have recently written the following code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.lang.Math;

  public class Circle{
    public static void main(String[] args){

      int d;
      int a;
      int v;

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please enter the value for the radius:");
      double radius = keyboard.nextDouble();

   d = 2*radius;
   a = 4*Math.PI*Math.pow(radius, 2)) ;
   v = 4/3*Math.PI*Math.pow(radius, 3) ;

   System.out.println("The diameter of the sphere is: "+ d);
   System.out.println("TThe surface area of the sphere is: "+ a);
   System.out.println( "The volume of the sphere is: "+ v);

}
```

}
However, it doesn't work and keeps saying this:

```
  Circle.java:15: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
d = 2 * radius;
      ^
  Circle.java:16: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
a = 4 * Math.PI * (radius*radius) ;
                ^
  Circle.java:17: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
v = 4/3 * Math.PI * (radius*radius*radius) ;
```

Can someone help please and explain the error that I have made? Any help is appreciated. **Thank you!!!!!**

Comment: Change your `int` variables to `double`. The values you are trying to assign to them are not integers.

Comment: `radius` is a double. why is `d` an int?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to assign a `double` value to an `int` variable (in lines 15,16,17)

you can solve it by changing the variables from `int` to `double`:

```
//...
double d;
double a;
double v;
//...
```

or by casting the double values to int (this will round the result)

```
//...
d = (int)(2*radius);
a = (int)(4*Math.PI*Math.pow(radius, 2));
v = (int)(4/3*Math.PI*Math.pow(radius, 3));
//...
```

Comment: One correction: casting a double to an int doesn't round, it just truncates the decimal portion.